# Composer error on installing to phpBB

Tags: php, json, windows, server, composer-php

I want to start making my own mods for PHPBB however I am having trouble setting up composer.

I have installed composer to my windows server and I run this in my command line

composer require :

```
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\Servers\5\localuser\gorrors\httpdocs\community
```

and I get this error:

> "`UnexpectedValueExpection`" cannot parse version.

When googling this error message everyone else seems to fix the error by running selfupdate however when I do this it says I have the latest version?

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be great

Comment: What are you trying to do with that folder?

Comment: I am getting this error PHP Fatal error:  Composer dependencies have not been set up yet, run 'php ../composer.phar install' from the phpBB directory to do so when trying to make a custom login so Im trying to install the composer files to the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using the [require command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) wrong here. It is used to add a specified package to the `composer.json` file as one that your project depends on.

As for the expected package name... From the [manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md):

> The package name consists of a vendor name and the project's name. Often these will be identical - the vendor name just exists to prevent naming clashes. It allows two different people to create a library named **json**, which would then just be named **igorw/json** and **seldaek/json**.

After specifying dependencies you can perform [composer install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install), which will search for the packages from the [set up repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository). Note that:

> By default only the [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) repository is registered in Composer. You can add more repositories to your project by declaring them in **composer.json**.

Comment: I am getting [05-Oct-2016 17:59:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Composer dependencies have not been set up yet, run 'php ../composer.phar install' from the phpBB directory to do so. in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\s19536047.onlinehome-server.info\httpdocs\community\includes\startup.php on line 170 error.... I have installed composer to the server. Do I need to install composer to PHPBB directory some how?